# Image doesn't appear in 'Render Layers' node in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to follow some tutorials on compositing but I am failing a the first hurdle. In every tutorial, when they open the compositor tab, the image appears in the 'render layers' node. However, as you can see, mine doesnt? [image]

Comment: Have you rendered the image? The image has at least be rendered once to appear there.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thankyou for responding. I am not sure I understand. This is an image sequence imported into blender. I have just tried RENDER -> RENDER ANIMATION but this still doesnt help after its finished rendering

Comment: The _Render Layers_ node provides a rendered image from a camera in a scene in Blender, not an imported sequence strip from the _Video Sequence Editor_. Whatever appears there has to be in the scene. You can import image sequences there, too, but with _Shift+A > Add > Input > Image Sequence_. Also, watch those tutorials carefully: they have rendered a scene with F12 or _Render > Render Image_ before opening the _Compositor_, otherwise there will be no image in the _Render Layers_ node upon opening.